# How to find and check all dynamic child checkboxes in tree using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, dynamic, tree

I have added check-boxes dynamically to all the element and successfully added the functionality to select all checkboxes but not able to do the selection for the parent child checkboxes in tree structure means if i select the "Asia" it should select all "Estern Asia" and "Southern Asia", if i select Estern Asia it should select all country and vice versa.

```js
var json ={"Asia": [{"regionList": [{"regionName": "Eastern Asia","Countrylist": [{"countryName": "China","subCountryList": [{"subCountryName": "Southern China"},{"subCountryName": "Eastern China"}]},{"countryName": "Hong Kong"}]},{"regionName": "Southern Asia","Countrylist": [{"countryName": "India"},{"countryName": "Pakistan"}]}]}]};
var html = '';
$.each(json, function(i1, object) {
html += '<li><input type="checkbox" /><b class=' + i1 + ' ><a name="' + i1 + '" >' + i1 + '</a></b>';
  $.each(object, function(i2, continent) {
    html += '<ul>';
    $.each(continent.regionList, function(i3, region) {
     html += '<li><input type="checkbox" /><b>' + region.regionName + '</b>';
     $.each(region.Countrylist, function(i4, country) {
      html += '<ul><li><input type="checkbox" />' + country.countryName;
      if (country.subCountryList) {
      $.each(country.subCountryList, function(i5, subCountry) {
       html += '<ul><li><input type="checkbox" />' + subCountry.subCountryName + '</li></ul>';
      });
     };
     html += '</li></ul>';
    });
    html += '</li>';
  });
  html += '</ul>';
 });
 html += '</li>';
});

$('#regionContent ol').html(html);
$('#selectAll').click(function() {
  if(this.checked) {
 $('#regionContent input[type="checkbox"]').each(function() { 
  this.checked = true;               
 });
  }else{
 $('#regionContent input[type="checkbox"]').each(function() {
  this.checked = false;                       
 });
  }
});
```

```css
li, ol{list-style:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="regionContent">
    <input type="checkbox" id="selectAll">All Countries
    <ol></ol>
</div>
```

Comment: I just wanted to point out that at the size of your jQuery code it would be way more readable/managable to use a template engine like [MustacheJS](http://mustache.github.io/) or the like. I'd say that the complexity seems to warrant an MV* framework like [backbone](http://backbonejs.org/), [angular](https://angularjs.org/) or my personal favorite [knockout](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-custom-elements.html)

Comment: i know it is more easy to do this task using these superb framework. But i have no option to use these :(

Comment: I see, I know the drill all too well ... happy coding, anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split the work into two.

1. Mark the child nodes as per the state of the current checkbox.
2. Walk through the parent nodes and mark their state as per their
   immediate child node state.

**Edited:**

```js
var json = {
  Asia: [{
    regionList: [{
      regionName: "Eastern Asia",
      Countrylist: [{
        countryName: "China",
        subCountryList: [{
          subCountryName: "Southern China"
        }]
      }, {
        countryName: "Hong Kong"
      }]
    }, {
      regionName: "Southern Asia",
      Countrylist: [{
        countryName: "India"
      }, {
        countryName: "Pakistan"
      }]
    }]
  }]
};

var html = '';
$.each(json, function(i1, object) {
  html += '<li><input type="checkbox"/><b><a name="' + i1 + '" >' + i1 + '</a></b>';
  $.each(object, function(i2, continent) {
    html += '<ul>';
    $.each(continent.regionList, function(i3, region) {
      html += '<li><input type="checkbox"/><b>' + region.regionName + '</b><ul>';
      $.each(region.Countrylist, function(i4, country) {
        html += '<li><input type="checkbox"/>' + country.countryName;
        if (country.subCountryList) {
          html += '<ul>';
          $.each(country.subCountryList, function(i5, subCountry) {
            html += '<li><input type="checkbox"/>' + subCountry.subCountryName + '</li>';
          });
          html += '</ul>';
        };
        html += '</li>';
      });
      html += '</ul></li>';
    });
    html += '</ul>';
  });
  html += '</li>';
});

$(function() {
  $('#list').html(html);
  $('#regionContent').on('change', 'input[type=checkbox]', onChange);
});

var topNodes = function(chkbx) {
  return $(chkbx).closest('ul').closest('li');
};

var markTopNodes = function(nodes) {
  if (!nodes.length) return;
  var chkbx = nodes.children('input').eq(0); //parent checkbox
  //get the immediate li's of the node
  var lis = nodes.children('ul').children('li');
  //get count of un-checked checkboxes
  var count = lis.children('input[type=checkbox]:not(:checked)').length;
  //mark if count is 0
  chkbx.prop('checked', !(count));
  //recursive call for other top nodes
  markTopNodes(topNodes(chkbx));
};

var onChange = function(e) {
  //for child nodes, checked state = current checkbox checked state
  $(this).closest('li').find('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', this.checked);
  //for parent nodes, checked if immediate childs are checked, but recursively
  markTopNodes(topNodes(this));
};
```

```css
li {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="regionContent">
  <ul>
    <!-- updated the html here -->
    <li>
      <input type='checkbox' />All Countries
      <ul id='list'></ul>
      <!-- added this -->
      <li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: @mrp This seems to do what you wanted, if it doesn't, could you elaborate?

Comment: @Arvind Its working fine with Chrome,FF,IE10. But when it comes to IE8 the tree structure is totally not working. I am using jquery version 1.9.1 which supposed to support all your method that you have used but I dont know why it is breaking. Can please suggest any solution. Thanks .

Answer (score 0):

try something along these lines:

```
$this.children('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', true);
```

Comment: select all is working. But I need to implement for the tree structure.

Comment: could you use the bold tag to single out the elements with children:
    $('b').on('click', function( ) {
        if($(this).checked) {
            $this.children('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', true);
        } else {
            $this.children('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', true);
        }

Comment: I am not able to select the checkbox element can you add your code to the fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

The following will check all children checkboxes, deeper than 1 level using `find` rather than `children`.

```
$(document.body).on('change', 'input[type=checkbox]', function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
        $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', true);
    }
});
```